# Why does webpack take 4 seconds to compile an empty react / redux project?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, webpack, redux

I am concerned it is compiling my `node_modules` despite me asking to exclude it.  How can I look and see what it is actually doing.  The output in the console looks like gibberish.  Is there a way to configure it to an output I can read.

This is a react/redux project. When I install react+ using `npm install react react-redux react-dom`, I assume this is in a readable form that webpack does not need to compile, hence the excluding of node_modules.

```
DEBUG: Webpack path:  /Users/c/top/framework/client
asset bundle.js 130 KiB [compared for emit] [minimized] (name: main) 2 related assets
orphan modules 55.3 KiB [orphan] 30 modules
cacheable modules 187 KiB
  modules by path ./node_modules/hoist-non-react-statics/ 5.36 KiB 3 modules
  modules by path ./node_modules/react/ 6.48 KiB 2 modules
  modules by path ./node_modules/react-dom/ 119 KiB 2 modules
  modules by path ./node_modules/scheduler/ 4.91 KiB
    ./node_modules/scheduler/index.js 198 bytes [built] [code generated]
    ./node_modules/scheduler/cjs/scheduler.production.min.js 4.72 KiB [built] [code generated]
  modules by path ./node_modules/react-is/ 2.48 KiB
    ./node_modules/react-is/index.js 196 bytes [built] [code generated]
    ./node_modules/react-is/cjs/react-is.production.min.js 2.29 KiB [built] [code generated]
  ./client/index.jsx + 20 modules 46.1 KiB [built] [code generated]
  ./node_modules/object-assign/index.js 2.06 KiB [built] [code generated]
webpack 5.69.0 compiled successfully in 3788 ms
```

**Relevant part of config file**

```
const input = `${ PATH_IN }/index.jsx`;


// babel-loader handles .js and .jsx files
const jsx = {
  include: PATH_IN,
  test: /\.jsx?/,
  exclude: /node_modules/,
  use: {
    loader: 'babel-loader',
    options: {
      presets: ['@babel/preset-env', '@babel/preset-react']
    }
  }
};
```

My project consists of a single file as follows: ( index.jsx )

```
import React        from 'react';
import ReactDOM     from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';

function App() {
  return null;
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App></App>
  </React.StrictMode>
  , document.getElementById('app'));
```

Comment: Define "gibberish". Define "empty project", there's still going to be a bundle created.

Comment: (1) Those assumptions aren't correct. Look at the sources (e.g. on [unpkg](https://unpkg.com/browse/react@17.0.2/)). (2) It's going to be difficult for anyone to answer this question unless you can define exhaustive and objective criteria for "an output you can read".

Comment: There is a single file with essentially nothing in it.  I posted the project or single file have you in the question.  What is it doing for 5 seconds every time I run it.  I assume it does not touch the `node_modules` but how can I be sure?

Comment: @jsec - Similarly, I would assume it does nothing with its own files, i.e webpack and webpack-cli.  I would assume that it only compiles the files I tell it to which in this case are .js, .jsx, and .css files starting with index.jsx which have no further dependencies.  Have updated to show entry point.

Comment: @Dave - if it is not gibberish please tell me what exactly it means, or not even exactly what it means, some sign of intelligence ... what is it doing?

Comment: It's building the app bundle for the app so it runs. You can be "sure" because you told it to exclude `node_modules` (almost always the right thing to do; occasionally there will be a module whose distro isn't already processed). "Essentially nothing in it" other than... React, which has its own code and dependencies. You can look at the resulting JS to see what's in it.

Comment: @user - your empty "project" is not actually empty, webpack must "compile" the 3 dependencies you have plus all the dependencies they have.  If you are looking for something smaller ... look into preact a library by a google developer.

Comment: I do find it odd that, `node_modules`, are not pre-compiled when installed, and more odd that @user excludes `node_modules`, but webpack still builds this part out as seen in the log

Comment: The "exclusion" just means that Webpack won't pre-process the files in `node_modules` using `babel-loader`.  Webpack _will_ still follow the dependency tree of imports, and include all of those `node_modules` files in the final bundle.  It's standard procedure in the JS ecosystem to _not_ pre-process anything from `node_modules`, because Webpack has no idea how those library files were authored. It's up to lib authors to pre-process their own source code as part of the publishing step.

Answer (score 0):

Your project is not actually empty.  It has 3 dependencies, and webpack will build out the dependency graph starting at index.jsx.  It will than build out the dependency graph for

- react
- react-dom
- react-redux

and each of their dependencies until all dependencies are packaged into a single file.